# Gatsby - Loading (Static Query) white screen

Tags: amazon-s3, gatsby, amazon-cloudfront, browser-cache, gatsby-plugin

I have Gatsby.js project where I am experiencing this issue, where when navigating or loading a page I am getting a white screen page where it says "Loading Static Query", there are no errors in development nor build time.

I have seen other people experiencing this issue.

I have updated Gatsby version **3.8.0 -> 4.6.0**

My built is uploaded to AWS S3 as static website hosting, it also has AWS Cloudfront in-front as Content Delivery Network and catching.

Here I would like to mention when deploying new features we invalidate Cloudfront cache.

The issue is **not happening** when on Incognito or if I clear all browser cache and storage.

I am not sure what to reproduce here

This is my Gatsby Static Query implementation (not sure if this causes the problem, despite it says so)

I am using **StaticQuery** for my **Layout component** that fetches data that is reusable for all components.

```
import { graphql, StaticQuery } from "gatsby";
const query = graphql`
  {
    allSanityTranslations {
      edges {
        node {
          data {
            key
            translate {
              en
              se
              ch
            }
          }
        }
      }
    } .........

const Layout = ({
  children,
  showNav,
  showFooter,
  seo,
  currentPage,
  url,
  entity,
}) => (
  <StaticQuery
    query={query}
    render={(data) => (
      <LocaleProvider
        currentPage={currentPage}
        entity={entity}
        translations={
          data && data.allSanityTranslations
            ? MapEdgesToNodes(data.allSanityTranslations)
            : []
        } ..Children...
```

As it says in Gatsby documentation StaticQuery is running on build time.

Does it matter if the query is too big ?

I am also doing `gatsby clean` before new builds.

This is the screen:

[image: gatsby loading static query]

**UPDATE:**

Due to further investigation, I have noticed that this is happening  when I deploy new version with code changes and code changes.

The "Loading Static Query screen" is showing on every page navigation that wasn't refreshed.

**If I delete everything in my browsers -> Cache Storage this is NOT happening anymore. So I think is connected with the cache.**

I am using [gatsby-plugin-offline](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-offline/) and that creates to IDs in the Cache Storage:

1. gatsby-plugin-offline-runtime-... (page-data etc..)
2. gatsby-plugin-offline-precache-... (webpack and other js files)

This is my **gatsby-config.js** regarding to this:

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
  options: {
    name: "MyWebsite",
    short_name: "MyWebsite",
    start_url: "/",
    background_color: "#2bb6ef",
    theme_color: "#2bb6ef",
    display: "standalone",
    icon: "static/assets/images/logo/logo-icon.svg",
    icon_options: {
      purpose: `any maskable`,
    },
    include_favicon: true,
  },
},
{ resolve: `gatsby-plugin-offline` },
```

Other than that I am using Sanity as source.

Comment: The issue is the result of the migration? I mean, does it work in version 3.8?

Comment: No, it was happening in 3.8.0, then I upgraded hoping it will be fixed

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue after updating my data queries and removing `gatsby-plugin-offline`, my setup is pretty much identical to yours.

What fixed this for me was adding [`gatsby-plugin-remove-serviceworker`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gatsby-plugin-remove-serviceworker) to ensure the service worker created by `gatsby-plugin-offline` was properly removed.

You can use this approach to remove the Service Worker altogether (sw.js), and then re-create it using `gatsby-plugin-offline` if needed. In my case the Service Worker was using invalid cache to run, so the only way to actually get the site working was by emptying cache, that is, for all those users who had the site cached in the first place.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am bit confused. What this mean for PWA ? Is service worker being removed on each page load ? How do I recreate it and when ?